# Executing from RAM ARM Cortex M4

Tags: c, assembly, linker, arm, bootloader

I'm really confused by scatter files and the steps necessary to execute in RAM (for a bootloader).

From my understanding the startup.S file and sysinit need to be execute from Flash, and during that time the vector table needs to be copied over to RAM before jumping to main?

I also don't really understand the purpose of the scatter file, if I am copying the vectors and code to ram before jumping why do I even need it.

Here's my wrong scatter file:

```
LR_IROM1 0x14000000 0x00400000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x14000000 0x00400000  {  ; load address = execution address
    startup.o (RESET, +FIRST)
     * (InRoot$$Sections)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x10000000 0x00020000  {  ; RW data
    *.o
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x20000000 0x00010000 {
    * (+RO,+RW,+ZI)
  }
}
```

Comment: Linker scripts are essential part of any project. They say the linker where to place the compiled code, how to calculate the address, define symbols and another stuff. You need to read the documentation and get some basics of the program compilation linking and execution

Comment: Yea I'm trying to go through the documentation but I was hoping someone could share a basic scatter file for such a setup (have code in flash but execute in ram including vector table). I can manage the startup file myself, but it's hard to tell if I'm on the right track when I'm second guessing the linker file.

Comment: Yea I really don't understand scatter files but I found some good explanations. I'll leave this question up in case anyone thinks they could help out, otherwise just ignore it - Peter is right I need to go back and review some things.

Comment: The linker script and bootstrap are intimately related.  Whichever toolchain you are using you need to design both as a pair.  Cant have one without the other.  But before you do that, are you planning on having the bootloader and the application live separately on flash?  Do you have two erase blocks?  Or are you planning on having the bootloader as part of the application?  A one erase block solution?

Comment: How you move the vectors is to write to the VTOR register which the cortex-m4 supports on the surface but always read up on the docs to see if this is a compile time option for the core, some arm cores (cortex-m and cortex-a, arm11, etc) support it some dont so dont always assume this solution is available.  If your core doesnt support VTOR and you only have one erase block then you cannot rely on 
 (cant use)interrupts/exceptions other than reset, so that pretty much solves the problem.

Comment: The bootloader is separate from the application, and I don't need to update it just the application - so I guess that would be one erase block.

Comment: a ram based program that is loaded from flash can be implemented with the most trivial linker script.  it is two programs one is the ram based bootloader, compiled and linked for ram.  the other is a handful/dozen lines of assembly that does the copy and jump.  no reason these have to be part of one program linked at one time.

Comment: I thought the VTOR just tells the processor WHERE the vectors are they still need to be copied there beforehand though.

Comment: so if you have one erase block then you have the bootloader on that flash, it boots copies and jumps to ram, runs in ram, allows the application to load where to ram and run in ram or are you allowing the application to be written to flash, overwriting the bootloader and not having a bootloader left after one application write?

Comment: not of you build them to be there, when you copy the bootloader from flash, the vector table for that bootloader is part of that depending on how you build it.  you build that vector table as well as the rest of .text as well as .data as well as .bss as well as .rodata, etc to be based in ram at the right places.

Comment: And yea I just need to figure out the trivial linker script for the ram based program as you were saying. I don't even understand what the directives in the linker script mean at the moment (at least fully) so trying to get that down first  as per Peter's suggestion.

Comment: Yes it writes to flash but in a different sector to not overwrite the bootloader obviously. The bootloader would then jump to the appropriate place if it's already in flash and isn't receiving an upgrade request from the host.

Comment: so that means the bootloader sector is not going to be erased, just the application, so there is more than one erase block, if the bootloader sector is not being erased then why bother to copy and jump to ram at all?  Is this a requirement of the part in question that you can have multiple erase "blocks" (sectors, pages, choose the appropriate term from their datasheet, i am calling them blocks like all tissues are kleenex, all soft drinks are cokes)  but you cannot execute out of one while erasing/programming the other?

Comment: your application will not be starting at the entry point of the processor so it will also need to have the vector table moved (VTOR) and/or the bootloader which does start at the entry point will have to be designed to generically trampoline to fixed locations in the application space, where the application is built for those landing spots.  (either way you have to solve the vector table problem).

Comment: likewise if you need to move the bootloader to ram to do the load function but a VTOR solution is not available and the chip doesnt have a chip specific solution (doesnt have to be an ARM solution, not uncommon for chip vendors to solve this) then you have the same problem, except you will want one solution for both the bootloader and the application, that could mean the bootloader  has to trampoline into ram, then the application has to setup trampolines into flash in its address space.  or design the bootloader so that it has no reason to need interrupts or exceptions and solve that problem.

Comment: it is not uncommon to have the bootloader designed such that its exception/interrupt entry points are a little bit of code that reads the handler address from ram allowing the application not only at compile time but at run time be able to set and change the handler address, say the application itself can load and run programs.  but you have to decide if you really need this complication for the applications.  In this case I think VTOR is going to save you the headaches.

Comment: so read your datasheet, figure out how many separate erase blocks/sectors you have, if more than one can you execute in one while erasing/programming another.  design the boot portion of your bootloader how it bounces over to the application (does it even detect if one is there).  decide how you are going to choose between boot and load.  the chip specs may determine your choices for where the loader has to run, and from the chip spec what the rules are for flashing, likely you dont need any interrupts/exceptions, but YMMV.

Comment: as well as what does the chip provide for re-mapping address space starting at zero, or does the arm core offer a solution (again I think that is true for the cortex-m4, but can the chip vendor defeat that or choose not to support it?)

Answer (score 1):

One solution for the bootloaders ram based linker script.  Assuming you are using the gnu linker.  There is more than one way to do this.

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ram
}
```

If your code requires .bss to be zeroed you can add more code to the linker script and more code to the bootstrap, but gnu will do this for you  if you use the above and guarantee there is at least one byte of .data somewhere (it will pad .bss with zeros to get the .data item(s) in the right relative place when doing the objcopy to a binary).  Your choice on how to solve that one though.  If you dont need .bss zeroed then swap .data and .bss make the binary smaller.  you are either copying zeros in a very very efficient loop, or writing zeros in a maybe as efficient loop if you work the alignments in the linker script.

the copy and jump side if it would only need something like this

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
}
```

worst case (for a simple assembly copy and jump), may be able to get rid of the .rodata line

The above are for gnu ld assuming that is what you are using, note that the memory names dont have meaning, you can instead do this:

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > bob
}
```

or

```
MEMORY
{
    joe : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > joe
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > joe
}
```

or

```
MEMORY
{
    pizza : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > pizza
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > pizza
}
```

or

```
MEMORY
{
    thehut : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
    pizza : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > thehut
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > thehut
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > pizza
    .data : { *(.data*) } > pizza AT > thehut
}
```

you can attack things in the MEMORY or in the SECTIONS side with gnu ld.  if you feel the need to have two .texts perhaps two .datas two .bss, etc (one for the copy/jump portion of the bootloader and one for the bootloader itself and have one linker script and link for all of the bootloader) you can do the this AT that thing or take the approach you are taking.  But as well as the bootstrap for each being intimately connected to the linker script, you also have to use toolchain specific solutions to make the bootloader on ram fit into the proper .text/.bss, etc by either overriding them into some other (.my_bl_text...) or calling out object file names in the linker script or other solutions.  Unfortunately the gnu linker script language has many features, and at the same time the documentation is more of a reference assuming you already know the language.  Difficult to see how folks who have written elaborate linker scripts figured that out from the existing gnu documentation, and then trying to write your first one or modify someone elses.  I recommend two programs the ram program and the copy jump program that contains the ram program as data.